# Is the biblatex toggle behavior expected or should the result stabilize

Tags: biblatex, citing, sorting

In my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100683/7561) an issue arose due to the use of multiple bibliographies in the given [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100726/7561), that I extended [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100790/7561).

So the issue is that the numbering in the second bibliography toggles between two states, shown below:

[image: fixed]
[image: fixed toggle]

Every run of `pdflatex` toggles between these two states. Is it a glitch? I haven't tested further, but as Andrew mentioned in the comments the problem may be the use of `defernumbers`. However, without them the second bibliography stays unsorted.

Is it possible to stabilize the result? or is there a problem somewhere else when using the two bibliographies?

**Edit.** This is a minimal version of the example below that also produces the same toggling behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}
% include bib from full example here
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,citestyle=numeric,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\bibliography{ref2}

\begin{document}
\cite{J2010, Z2010, Z2007, C2009, T2010}    
\printbibliography
\newrefsection
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[resetnumbers=true,keyword=publication,type=article,heading=subbibliography,title={Journals}]
\printbibliography[keyword=publication,type=inproceedings,heading=subbibliography,title={Conferences}]
\end{document}
```

**Original code for pictures:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ref2.bib}
@INPROCEEDINGS{C2009,
  author = {C H.},
  title = {M},
  booktitle = {C},
  year = {2009},
  month = oct
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{J2010,
  author = {J O.},
  title = {L},
  booktitle = {P},
  year = {2010}
}
@ARTICLE{T2010,
  author = {X B.},
  title = {E},
  year = {2010},
  month = jun,
  journal = {I}
}
@ARTICLE{Z2010,
  author = {B},
  title = {L},
  year = {2010},
  volume = {19},
  month = feb,
  journal = {I}
}
@ARTICLE{Z2007,
  author = {B},
  title = {H},
  year = {2007},
  month = jan,
  journal = {I}
}
@ARTICLE{K2013,
  author = {K O.},
  title = {B},
  year = {2013},
  month = feb,
  journal = {I},
  keywords = {publication}
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{K2012,
  author = {K  O.},
  title = {S},
  booktitle = {I},
  year = {2012},
  month = jul,
  keywords = {publication}
}
@ARTICLE{M2011,
  author = {M O.},
  title = {M},
  year = {2011},
  month = jun,
  journal = {L},
  keywords = {publication}
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{M2010,
  author = {M O.},
  title = {S},
  booktitle = {A},
  year = {2010},
  month = aug,
  keywords = {publication}
}
@ARTICLE{M2012,
  author = {M O.},
  title = {S},
  year = {2012},
  month = jul,
  journal = {I},
  keywords = {publication}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,bibencoding=utf8,sorting=cymat,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareSortingScheme{ymdtn}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
    \literal{99}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
    \literal{99}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
  }
  \sort[direction=descending]{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort{
    \name{sortname}
    \name{author}
    \name{editor}
    \name{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}
% sort in citation order and then by year/month, and author and title
\DeclareSortingScheme{cymat}{
  \sort{\citeorder}
  \sort{
      \field{sortyear}
      \field{year}
      \literal{0}
    }
    \sort{
      \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{month}
      \literal{0}
    }
    \sort[direction=descending]{
      \field[padside=left,padwidth=2,padchar=0]{day}
      \literal{99}
    }
  \sort{
      \name{sortname}
      \name{author}
      \name{editor}
      \name{translator}
      \field{sorttitle}
      \field{title}
  }
}

\bibliography{ref2}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\cite{J2010, Z2010, Z2007, C2009, T2010}
\printbibliography%[sorting=cymat] % removed the sorting from here to the package
\newrefsection
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[resetnumbers=true,keyword=publication,type=article,heading=subbibliography,title={Journals},sorting=ymdtn]
\printbibliography[keyword=publication,type=inproceedings,heading=subbibliography,title={Conferences},sorting=ymdtn]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The example can be minimalised to `\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,citestyle=numeric,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}` and a sort scheme with just `\citeorder`.

Comment: This is expected - dealing with defernumbers is actually very hard and requires .aux file support which is responsible for this. It's acceptable because there is no need to run again and toggle it once the "please rerun latex" messages stop. If *this* doesn't stablise then that's a problem.

Comment: @PLK that is precisely the issue. Every run of pdflatex switches from one sorting order to the next. I'm not sure if that will produce problems in bigger documents.

Comment: @adn I can't reproduce your issue with biber 1.5. But to restate PLK's comment: This would only be considered a problem if (1) the log file shows a persistent "rerun LaTeX" message or (2) the last log-instructed rerun doesn't give the expected output.